# see execution time of javascript code next to each call

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, debugging, v8

Is it possible to see execution time like the image bellow, but in **Node** without the gibberish in vscode javascript debugger or without using the `console.time('debug')` and `console.timeEnd('debug')` functions ?

[image: source test function performance]

Edit 1 :
Something like this is gibberish to me, too hard to read.
I take the chart as an exemple here but *top down* or *bottom up* views are the same to me.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "*without the gibberish in vscode javascript debugger*"?

Comment: How did you take that screenshot? Why not do the same on a nodejs script?

Comment: that screenshot is from chrome source view if you make an html file who load a javascript file, and go to _performance tab > reload button > stop recording_  after a time and go to _Sources tab_ of your script you will see the exact same thing

Comment: Just open the devtools for nodejs and do exactly the same profiling

Comment: It doesn't have the same behaviour that's why I posted this question.

Comment: you use "process.uptime()" place one at you starting point, another one at the end, then substract.

Comment: @GérardLeCloerec Just switch to the "sources" tab and you should see the timings there, no?

Comment: @Jerome no code are needed to see this in browser javascript code.

Comment: @Bergi for some reason it's not working, no timing are shown, maybe i missed something with my configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of this tools:

- Execution profiler for nodejs: [sample](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/)
- ExecTimer, nodejs package: [via npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exectimer)

Comment: Execution profiler are not what i asked for and ExecTimer need to write code in that case why not just write `console.time()` as it seem 100% faster and easier.

Comment: So you want to do something automatically. I guess there is no way to do nothing and gain something :). That plugin of Vscode is written by someone and is implemented by some lines of code!